# .NET7 Json serialization: cannot handle circular references

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-7.0

I have these tables in my db:

```
- Turns
- Jobs
- Turns_Jobs (a turn may have multiple jobs, a single job may span across multiple turns)
- Managers (each job has a manager)
```

These are the corresponding classes:

```
- Turn
   - int TurnID
   - ...
   - virtual ICollection<Turn_Job> TurnJobs

- Job
   - int JobID
   - ...
   - int ManagerID
   - virtual Manager Manager
   - ...
   - virtual ICollection<Turn_Job> JobTurns

- Turn_Job
   - int TurnID
   - ...
   - virtual Turn Turn
   - int JobID
   - virtual Job Job

- Manager
   - ManagerID
   - Name
```

I'm trying to serialize the following query:

```
var q = await _db.Turns
    .Include(x => x.TurnJobs).ThenInclude(x => x.Job).ThenInclude(x => x.Manager)
    .Where(x => true; /* real application has some conditions here */ )
    .Select(x => x)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Usually I would do:

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(q, new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web) { ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve });
```

but this throws the following exception:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: The object or value could not be serialized. Path: $.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: CurrentDepth (64) is equal to or larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64. Cannot write the next JSON object or array.
```

It seems that circular reference is not detected and/or correctly handled.

If I ignore references:

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(r, new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web) { ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles });
```

the exception becomes:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path: $.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.Job.JobTurns.Turn.TurnJobs.TurnID.
```

Comment: What is the purpose of serialization? Do you want to save it somewhere and deserialize later or you want to share the data with some other service?

Comment: This code is actually part of a blazor application. The query is run in a controller and result should be sent to the client. Actual code is ``q = ... ; Return Ok(q, new JsonSerializerOptions(...) {...};`` and it gives the same exception.

Comment: I would highly recommend not to expose the whole model to a client. Provide only what the client really needs and nothing more. It will protect you from serialization/deserialization issues and will make your service interface much more clear.